# How to fix the running of my program in terms of conditional statements and output in C?

Tags: c, input, printf, conditional-statements, scanf

I have a problem with my input for my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int confirm()
{
    char c;

    printf("Confirm (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    while (scanf("%c", &c))
    {
        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c == 'n')
        {
            printf("\nThank you. \n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInput not recognised, ry again. \n");
            printf("Confirm (y/n): ");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    confirm();
    return 0;
}
```

When it executes, it asks the first question and inputting the answer is fine. However after entering the character (either y or n) the program prints the second question and stops. The whole program is not running. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is it finishing and returning?

Comment: `while(scanf("%c",&c))` --> `while(scanf(" %c",&c)==1)`. Note the space before `%c`. It skips whitespace characters until the first non-whitespace character. And please, in the future, don't post images. Post the code directly by copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Loose the first scanf at line 9 and (for me) it then seem to work correctly: if ynYN is entered then the confirm function exits, otherwise it continues looping